# Manipulating surds and exponentiation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Sir,

Can you tell me if my below simple calculation is right for -1/2 root of 1/2?

$$\sqrt[-1/2]{ 1/2} = (-1/2)^2 = 1/4$$

I got this doubt because when I am trying this in http://web2.0calc.com/ , i am getting the an error "Invalid Negative Argument"

Thanks.

Comment: When you write, "$-1/2$ root of $1/2$", do you mean, $(1/2)^{-1/2}$? or do you mean $\root{-1/2}\of{1/2}$?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I meant the second one, but the sign is changed. i.e., 1/2 root_symbol -1/2

Comment: That seems unlikely. The 3rd root of 7, for example, is $\root3\of7$, not $\root7\of3$.

Comment: What do you mean the sign is changed? As in $\sqrt[1/2]{-1/2}=(-1/2)^{2}=1/4$?

Comment: @ Daniel Rust, yes, that is exactly the one I am trying to solve.

Comment: @ Daniel Rust, so is 1/4 is the answer and the steps are right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1/2)^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{(1/2)^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/2}}=\frac{1}{1/\sqrt 2}=\sqrt2$$

$$(-1/2)^{1/2}=\sqrt{-1/2}=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt2}=\frac{i}{\sqrt2}$$

$$\sqrt [1/2]{-1/2}=(-1/2)^{\frac{1}{1/2}}=(-1/2)^2=1/4$$

$$\sqrt [-1/2]{1/2}=(1/2)^{\frac{1}{-1/2}}=(1/2)^{-2}={\frac{1}{(1/2)^2}}=4$$

Comment: It's not clear to me that either of these is what OP wants.

Comment: @Adi Dani, sorry, the expression is what @ Daniel Rust just typed.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing what you've said in the comments, we would normally say that $$\sqrt[\frac{1}{2}]{-\frac{1}{2}}$$ is the '$\frac{1}{2}$'th root of $-\frac{1}{2}$. Of course this is a bit of a mouthful and I don't think anyone would actually say this. By the usual rules of surds, we have the equality $$\sqrt[\frac{1}{2}]{-\frac{1}{2}}=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/\frac{1}{2}}=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer is perfect.  Could you also pl tell me why you say that such an expression is very rare?

Comment: Well, in practice people don't often take the $x$th root of something unless $x$ is a natural number greater than $1$. At least, we wouldn't say it in those terms. We're much more likely to talk about the $1/x$th power instead, as it's perhaps less ambiguous, and easier to manipulate. Of course, if you're learning this stuff in class, what we do *in practice* might not matter - so you shouldn't listen to this if you need to learn something to pass a class.